# opel corsa 2010 manual transmission abs acceleration

Tags: manual-transmission

hi there does  any one have info, I have a opel corsa 2010 manual transmission, when changing gears 4 to 5 in neutral time engine rpm goes to maximum without pressing gas pedal, no faulty codes stored, abs light come on when issue happen

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! So I understand, this only happens when you shift up in the gears? It will go straight up to redline?